# Do I have to download a specific package for working Ad function?

Tags: r

I am doing an example with R. Actually,I don't know programming very well. So I didn't understand this problem. Do I have to download a specific package for this function or is there a problem with my data?

```
X.m <- Ad(to.monthly(X))
```

I am trying to work this function and program is saying:

```
Error in Ad(to.monthly(X)) : could not find function "Ad"
```

Comment: If somebody put function `An` in a package, then probably yes, you need to load it before you are able to use it. You should install the package beforehand to be able to do that, though. Where did you find this code? It must have a `library()` call somewhere to give you some hints on the name.

Comment: It was a homework. Our Teacher gave it and Said that follow same step with different data. However, ı couldn’t work this function. I searched a little for it but I couldn’t find which package I need.